# why is promise resolved object undefined?

Tags: node.js, promise

Here is my code

```
exports.createNewSellerTicket =  function(ticketData,fileNames){
   var SellerTicket = ticketSchema.SellerTicketModel;
   sellerTicket = new SellerTicket(ticketData);
   sellerTicket.save()
   .then(function (ticket) {
            logger.info("New ticket created"));
    fsSrv.createSellerTicketsDirectory(ticket._id);
  })
  .then((obj)=>{  /// obj is null here ??? could not figure it out??
       //// some stuff on obj
    const query = { _id: ticketData._id };
    SellerTicket.updateOne(query, { attachments: pathArr }, {}, function(err,res){
      if (err){
        logger.error(err);
      } 
      logger.info("seller ticket id:"+ticketData._id+" updated");
    });
  })
  .catch(err =>{
    logger.error(err);
  })
}
```

Here is the method of fsSrv.createSellerTicketsDirectory

```
function createSellerTicketsDirectory(ticketId){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
    try{
      
      var dir = "/"+ticketId;
       fs.mkdirSync(dir);
      var obj = new Object();
      obj.dirPath = dir;
      obj.ticketId = ticketId;
      resolve(obj);
    }
    catch(err){
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}
exports.createSellerTicketsDirectory = createSellerTicketsDirectory;
```

when I debug it, obj is containing correct values but when it returns back to .then(obj), here the obj is undefined. I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: Since it's 2020 and `async` and `await` are a thing, why not switch to that style and make your life a lot easier?

Comment: If you want this function to be chainable, don't forget to `return` your last promise.

Answer (score 1):

To chain you need to be very aware of what, if anything, you need to return from each `then` stage. In this case you dropped the ball. An easy fix:

```
.then(function (ticket) {
  logger.info("New ticket created"));

  // If you don't return here, the function returns undefined and
  // the next then() has nothing to work with.
  return fsSrv.createSellerTicketsDirectory(ticket._id);
})
```

This is way less messy if you just `async` it:

```js
exports.createNewSellerTicket = async function(ticketData,fileNames) {
   const SellerTicket = ticketSchema.SellerTicketModel;

   let sellerTicket = new SellerTicket(ticketData);
   let ticket = await sellerTicket.save();

   logger.info("New ticket created"));
   let obj = await fsSrv.createSellerTicketsDirectory(ticket._id);

   const query = { _id: ticketData._id };

   // Presuming a Promise is available here
   let res = await SellerTicket.updateOne(query, { attachments: pathArr });

   logger.info(`seller ticket id: ${ticketData._id} updated`);
}
```